# A question about integral notation and interpreting it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I was watching an introductory video series on  differential equations by Gilbert Strang. In one of the first videos there was a lesson on calculus you need to know to understand the rest of the series. After watching, I had a quick question about notation for integration. Specifically, The fundamental theorem of calculus was used to shown that

$$y(t) = \int_0^t e^{t-s} q(s) ds$$ solves $$\frac{dy}{dt}=y+q(t)$$

Using the product rule. The thing that confuses me is what (s) refers to in this context. I'm comfortable with basic integration from school, integrating e.g. x^2 etc. In the above example, I don't understand how the integral is between 0 and t, yet there is also an (s) term in there. Similarly, I don't understand how the integral has a ds at the end, shouldn't the whole thing not be done with respect to t?

Hopefully my question makes sense.
video and timestamp for context
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0BxAtprWts&t=240s

Comment: $\int_0^t e^{t-s} q(s) \, ds$ means exactly the same thing as $\int_0^t e^{t-x} q(x) \, dx$. The $s$ (or $x$) is just a "dummy variable". It can't equal $t$, though, because $t$ already has an identity in this context.

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you. I think also the fact that there was t in the limits of the integration confused me ($\int_0^t$) given that we're integrating with respect to s . Is the correct way to interpret this that s = t and s = 0 as the upper lower bounds, respectively, given that we're integrating with respect to s?